# SAP Education Server Instance for Purpose of Learning

Tags: sap-basis

For some years now, my company is using SAP software which had proven to be a very good software.

I am interested in opening SAP testing-education instance which will be used for learning purpose for students that will visit our company periodically. These are the most important features that this solution should have:

- this instance should contain dummy company code which should be with *same* by configuration as our main (production) server,
- all transactional data should be empty, except a few examples which are enough for learning purpose but do not reveal *real* data about company,
- this instance should be somehow virtually separated from *real* DEV-QAS-PRD and to be used only for learning and education purposes.

So these are my questions:

- is it possible to make replica of PRD server, delete transactional data on replica but to maintain configuration from PRD?
- is there any other way to achieve this aim beside one I have mentioned above?

Any help is appreciated and many thanks in advance for prompt replies!

All the best,
Mc

Comment: How exactly do you define "virtually separated"?

Comment: I meant that I could create virtual machine on server which would be just for purposes of instance which will be used for learning.

Answer (score 1):

Build your training system by making a [system copy](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-8324) of the production system. When you do a system copy, you can decide what you want to copy. Choose only the repository and the customizing, no users and no application data.

When you want a limited set of production-like data in your training system, you could get a [TDMS system](http://help.sap.com/saptdm) to transfer and anonymize a limited set of production data, but because of the involved cost I wouldn't recommend it unless you have some more use for it (like getting anonymized test data for DEV and QA systems).

To keep the production- and training system synchronized, configure your transport management system so that each transport which goes into the production-system also goes into the new training-system. This can be achieved by either placing them in parallel or by placing the training system behind the production system and have a regular auto-import.

Comment: This sounds like very good solution. However, I have few questions which are very important to me:

Comment: This sounds like very good solution. However, I have few questions which are very important to me: 1. Do I have to create new virtual machine on my server which will be used only for this special learning SAP instance? 2. Regarding copying limited set of production-like data via TMDS, since this is the higher cost, perhaps it is better when copying of repository and the customizing is made, I just enter same basic data so students could learn from it? On this way I don't use TMDS and I enter enough data for learning purposes. Many thank in advance for prompt reply. Sam

Comment: @MC2012 I wouldn't let any dev, qa- or training-system run on the same hardware as the production system, because you don't want performance or security impaired because someone does something unusual on the other instance. When you think entering some data manually is more cost-effective than an automatized solution, go for it. It really depends on how much data you need, which is a question I can not answer for you.